# Android bluetooth MAC obtained is 02:00:00:00:00:00

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-wifi, android-bluetooth

Trying to get the Bluetooth of an android phone with

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String bleMAC = bluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
```

the result of the function is **02:00:00:00:00:00**, i am expecting some thing the lines of **00:04:61:02:AA:FF**

Also noticed that wifi mac address are same as Bluetooth mac address. Can the wifi MAC address be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Per Android 6.0 Changes:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id

To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.

To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions.

Comment: So what's the solution? Adding those permissions won't fix the issue

Comment: there is no way to get Bluetooth MAC from the phone programmatically. It's android documentation itself

Comment: adding those do nothing

Answer (score 2):

According to Android document [WifiInfo API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo#getMacAddress()), an Android app has to be a system app and get below 2 permissions:

- android.Manifest.permission.LOCAL_MAC_ADDRESS
- Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

I tried on a rooted device of Android 10, it worked well.